# Why do these two list comprehensions yield different results?

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to determine the correlation coefficient between two statistics (in this case age and health insurance cost), and I googled how to use list comprehensions to sum values in nested dictionaries. The tutorial told me to use:

`average_age = sum(data[i][stat1] for i in data if i)/len(data)`

but provided no explanation for the `if i` part. I also tried:

`average_age = sum(data[i][stat1] for i in data)/len(data)`

and it yielded a slightly different result (39.207025 vs 39.19282). If `i` is an integer, how can it be used in an if statement? And what does the if statement mean in this context?

Comment: Please give a sample data -- otherwise, the [mcve] is incompete and this is unanswerable.

Comment: ...but to explain why your results are different, they are different because some of your data is being excluded from the `sum` operation in the first case, but not in the second.

Comment: Technically speaking these are actually generator expressions - list comprehensions are always inside [ ] https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator

Comment: To understand this your self all you have to do is print the two expressions e.g. `print(list(data[i][stat1] for i in data if i))` and `print(list(data[i][stat1] for i in data))` and assuming some of the entries in `data` are falsy you’ll see they are different lists - of course if none are falsy then the lists will be identical.

Comment: It almost looks like the `if i` is used to sum all but row (or column) 0,  which may be headers?   I might also be a string, but the same eliminate header row/column still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-part of a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will decided if that element is included or not

In the below example, you can see that any zero are excluded from the resulting list if you keep the if-part there, while without the if-part zeros will also be included. If you see `if x` and x is an integer, it will behave as `if x != 0`, that can make it easier to understand.

```py
>>> [x for x in (3,2,1,0,-1) if x]
[3, 2, 1, -1]
>>> [x for x in (3,2,1,0,-1)]
[3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

An integer in python can be used in conditions as it will evaluate to true unless zero in such contexts.

Comment: I know you mean something a bit different than what you say in your final statement.  Your statement implies that an integer used in a boolean context always equates to `True`.  That is, of course, not true.  You should update your answer to say "..as it will evaluate to `False` when its value is `0`, and `True` in any other case."

Comment: @Steve that's right. I typed too fast so an important part dropped there.

Comment: I think I understand. So if the index (i) is zero, then it wouldn’t be included in the data?

Comment: Oh no, not the index, the value. My example was poorly chosen. 